# Codeigniter input match a certain extension

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can I match a certain input type extension in CI 3.0 ?

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="some.dll" id="name" maxlength="24" class="form-control" placeholder="Example: some.dll">
```

I need to set rules allowing only .dll input, but I don`t know how.
Any help is apreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Using [file uploading](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) (disclaimer: codeigniter.com is not available from here right now) class, you should configure allowed file type.

Comment: @Tpojka - I am not uploading, I am accepting that name, and storing into the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way (pay attention on form field names changes I made too):

```
class Form extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dll', 'DLL file name', 'callback_dll_check');//change name and id in form view to dll and remove value attribute

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            //code for insert into DB
            //redirect('somewhere', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    public function dll_check($str)
    {
        $str = explode('.', $str);//
        if ( end($str) !== 'dll' )
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('dll', 'The %s field has to be of "dll" extension type.');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, but I get: Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name. And my previous rulles where like this: $this->form_validation->set_rules(array(
    array('field' => 'cheat_name', 
          'label' => 'lang:dll_based_cheat_name', 
          'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_dash|min_length[2]|max_length[24]'), ))

Comment: I `think i`m not capturing the error message properly

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file in codeigniter you are using

```
 $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
 $config['max_size']    = '100';
 $config['max_width']  = '1024';
 $config['max_height']  = '768';

 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

You can specify the 'dll' in $config['allowed_types'] at the time of initialization .

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'dll';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: But I am not uploading files, I am storing in database... what can I do in that case?